# I have a SAP generated file with many columns and some unwanted rows. How should I read directly into Pandas?

Tags: python, string, csv, pandas

My table:

```
Table To Be Searched MSEG
Number of hits                                                            273208
Maximum No. of Entri                                                           0
Runtime                00:24:17

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Mat. Doc. |MatYr|MvT|Material |Plnt|SLoc|Batch     |Customer|  Amount in LC|        Amount|    Quantity|BUn|    Qty in UnE|EUn|PO        |MatYr|Mat. Doc. |Order    |Profit Ctr|SLED/BBD  |Pstng Date|Entry Date|Time    |User name  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|4912693062|2015 |551|100062   |HDC2|0001|5G30MC1A11|        |         9.03 |         9.06 |      0.083 |CS |            2 |EA |          |     |          |         |IN1165B085|26.01.2016|01.08.2015|01.08.2015|01:13:16|O33462     |
|4912693063|2015 |501|166      |HDC2|0004|          |        |         0.00 |         0.00 |          2 |EA |            2 |EA |          |     |          |         |IN1165B085|          |01.08.2015|01.08.2015|01:13:17|O33462     |
|4912693320|2015 |551|101343   |HDC2|0001|5G28MC1A11|        |        53.73 |        53.72 |      0.500 |CS |           12 |EA |          |     |          |         |IN1165B085|25.01.2016|01.08.2015|01.08.2015|01:16:30|O33462     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Table To Be Searched MSEG
Number of hits                                                            273208
Maximum No. of Entri                                                           0
Runtime                00:24:17

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|Mat. Doc. |MatYr|MvT|Material |Plnt|SLoc|Batch     |Customer|  Amount in LC|        Amount|    Quantity|BUn|    Qty in UnE|EUn|PO        |MatYr|Mat. Doc. |Order    |Profit Ctr|SLED/BBD  |Pstng Date|Entry Date|Time    |User name  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|4912696602|2015 |344|100399   |HMH3|0001|5G29MH3S11|        |         0.00 |         0.00 |      9,061 |CS |        9,061 |CS |          |     |          |         |IN1165B074|26.01.2016|01.08.2015|01.08.2015|01:54:15|A70475     |
```

Its contains over more than 1 million rows. Previously I was converting this file first in a CSV using following Python code:

```
def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)

with open("Input.txt") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        with open("Out.csv", "a") as myfile:
            if line[:1] == '|':
                if hasNumbers(line) == True:
                    newline = line[1:-2].replace(' ','')
                    newline.translate(None, ",!.;")
                    myfile.write(newline+'\n')
```

Is there a better way to convert this kind of file to CSV format or how should I directly parse it to pandas?

Comment: Sorry is your sample data formatted as you've posted? i.e. with multiple tables using `----` and `|` to delimit the columns and rows?

Comment: Yes my sample data is same as the original one but with many rows between them

Comment: The answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/58269521/11262633 does not require opening the text file twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`itertools.ifilter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) to filter only the table data and a `csv.reader` to parse the important rows as follows:

```
import csv
import itertools
import StringIO

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
    for line in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == '|' and x[1].isalpha(), f_input):
        header = [cols.strip() for cols in next(csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(line), delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True))][1:-1]
        break

with open('input.txt', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header)
    for line in itertools.ifilter(lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == '|' and x[1] != '-' and not x[1].isalpha(), f_input):
        csv_input = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(line), delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True)
        csv_output.writerow([col.strip().translate(None, ",!.;") for col in next(csv_input)[1:-1]])
```

This would give you an output csv file as follows:

```
Mat. Doc.,MatYr,MvT,Material,Plnt,SLoc,Batch,Customer,Amount in LC,Amount,Quantity,BUn,Qty in UnE,EUn,PO,MatYr,Mat. Doc.,Order,Profit Ctr,SLED/BBD,Pstng Date,Entry Date,Time,User name
4912693062,2015,551,100062,HDC2,0001,5G30MC1A11,,903,906,0083,CS,2,EA,,,,,IN1165B085,26012016,01082015,01082015,01:13:16,O33462
4912693063,2015,501,166,HDC2,0004,,,000,000,2,EA,2,EA,,,,,IN1165B085,,01082015,01082015,01:13:17,O33462
4912693320,2015,551,101343,HDC2,0001,5G28MC1A11,,5373,5372,0500,CS,12,EA,,,,,IN1165B085,25012016,01082015,01082015,01:16:30,O33462
4912696602,2015,344,100399,HMH3,0001,5G29MH3S11,,000,000,9061,CS,9061,CS,,,,,IN1165B074,26012016,01082015,01082015,01:54:15,A70475
```

Comment: You got " " this in your fourth line. The file should not contain any of <" '>, because while parsing it give EOF error.

Comment: CSV format automatically adds quotes if the column contains a comma, otherwise it would be interpreted as another column. You can force quoting for all columns, but to suppress them you would need to parse out commas. This file will load correctly into Excel as is.

Comment: Can you also add one line of headers at the top if possible.

Comment: If will have `"` in our csv file then will get this error while parsing the file in to pandas:

`CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 73685, saw 4`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there is one more request your first program was parsed correctly. Sorry for that and but you haven't removed `"` or `'` this from the line which is giving me error. Thanks for the solution. If its possible for you can you tell me what should I change such that the script will remove `"` and `'` and add one set of header at the top. The error which I got was in the line 73685 because there was `"`. Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your question to add a sample row to your table that is causing the problem? Then I'll see what could be done.

Comment: @Martins Sorry mate it got parsed correctly. Is it possible to add one set of headers at the top.

Comment: My updated answer does already add a header to the file. You might need to add another `translate` to parse out any characters you don't wont.

Comment: Yeah Its done, maybe I was working with previous program only. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach based on the answer in [How to convert a SAP .txt extraction into a .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268816/how-to-convert-a-sap-txt-extraction-into-a-csv-file), which does not require opening the input file twice.

Here's the code from that answer, with @Martin Evans's clever technique of testing `row[1].isalpha` to determine if you have a header, and only export it once:

```
import csv

ii = 0

with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f_input, \
     open(str(ii + 1) + 'output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f_output:

    input_lines = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == '|' and x[1] == ' ', f_input)

    csv_input = csv.reader(input_lines, delimiter='|')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    found_header = False
    for row in csv_input:
        if not found_header and row[1].isalpha():
            found_header = True
        csv_output.writerow(col.strip() for col in row[1:-1])
```