# How to convert a SAP .txt extraction into a .csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a .txt file as in the example reported below. I would like to convert it into a .csv table, but I'm not having much success.

```
Mack3                                            Line Item Journal                                        Time 14:22:33     Date  03.10.2015
Panteni    Ledger 1L                                                                                    TGEPIO00/CANTINAOAS Page      20.001
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    Pstng Date|Entry Date|DocumentNo|Itm|Doc..Date |BusA|PK|SG|Sl|Account   |User Name   |LCurr|      Amount in LC|Tx|Assignment        |S|
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4919005298| 36|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |             0,85 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4919065298| 29|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |             2,53 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4919235298| 30|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |            30,00 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4119005298| 32|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |             1,00 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|9019005298| 34|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |            11,10 |  |20140107          | |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

The file in question is structure as a report from SAP. Practicing with python and looking in other posts I found this code:

```
    with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f_input:
        for line in filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == '|' and x[1].isalpha(), f_input):
            header = [cols.strip() for cols in next(csv.reader(StringIO(line), delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True))][1:-1]
            break
    with open('file.txt', 'rb') as f_input, open(str(ii + 1) + 'output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
        csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
        csv_output.writerow(header)
        for line in filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == '|' and x[1] != '-' and not x[1].isalpha(), f_input):
            csv_input = csv.reader(StringIO(line), delimiter='|', skipinitialspace=True)
            csv_output.writerow(csv_input)
```

Unfortunately it does not work for my case. In fact it creates empty .csv files and it seems to not read properly the csv_input.

Any possible solution?

Comment: Unless you expect that everybody here can pull "reports from SAP" out of thin air, you need to show a useful sample of your input text, along with the matching output you expect from that.

Comment: That being said, please don't post code you found someplace and ask us to fix it. That's not the idea of this website. Post code *you wrote* along with a problem description of the roadblock you hit while writing it, and a general idea of where you were meaning to go.

Comment: thank you Tomalak, I actually adapted the code to my scope as it was designed for python2. I will post you a sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input file can be treated as CSV once we filter out a few lines, namely the ones that do not start with a pipe symbol `'|'` followed by a space `' '`, which would leave us with this:

```
|    Pstng Date|Entry Date|DocumentNo|Itm|Doc..Date |BusA|PK|SG|Sl|Account   |User Name   |LCurr|      Amount in LC|Tx|Assignment        |S|
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4919005298| 36|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |             0,85 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4919065298| 29|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |             2,53 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4919235298| 30|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |            30,00 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|4119005298| 32|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |             1,00 |  |20140107          | |
|    07.01.2014|07.02.2014|9019005298| 34|07.01.2019|    |81|  |  |60532640  |tARFooWMOND |EUR  |            11,10 |  |20140107          | |
```

Your output is mainly empty because that `x[1].isalpha()` check is never true on this data. The character in position 1 on each line is always a space, never alphabetic.

It's not necessary to open the input file multiple times, we can read, filter and write to the output in one go:

```
import csv

ii = 0

with open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f_input, \
     open(str(ii + 1) + 'output.csv', 'w', encoding='utf8', newline='') as f_output:

    input_lines = filter(lambda x: len(x) > 2 and x[0] == '|' and x[1] == ' ', f_input)

    csv_input = csv.reader(input_lines, delimiter='|')
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        csv_output.writerow(col.strip() for col in row[1:-1])
```

Notes:

- You should *not* use binary mode when reading text files. Use `r` and `w` modes, respectively, and explicitly declare the file encoding. Choose the encoding that is the right one for your files.
- For work with the `csv` module, open files with `newline=''` (which lets the `csv` module pick the correct line endings)
- You can wrap multiple files in the `with` statements using the `\` at the end of the line.
- `StringIO` is completely unnecesary.
- I'm not using `skipinitialspace=True` because some of the columns also have spaces at the end. Therefore I'm calling `.strip()` manually on each value when writing the row.
- The `[1:-1]` is necessary to get rid of the superfluous empty columns (before the first and after the last `|` in the input)

Output is as follows

```
Pstng Date,Entry Date,DocumentNo,Itm,Doc..Date,BusA,PK,SG,Sl,Account,User Name,LCurr,Amount in LC,Tx,Assignment,S
07.01.2014,07.02.2014,4919005298,36,07.01.2019,,81,,,60532640,tARFooWMOND,EUR,"0,85",,20140107,
07.01.2014,07.02.2014,4919065298,29,07.01.2019,,81,,,60532640,tARFooWMOND,EUR,"2,53",,20140107,
07.01.2014,07.02.2014,4919235298,30,07.01.2019,,81,,,60532640,tARFooWMOND,EUR,"30,00",,20140107,
07.01.2014,07.02.2014,4119005298,32,07.01.2019,,81,,,60532640,tARFooWMOND,EUR,"1,00",,20140107,
07.01.2014,07.02.2014,9019005298,34,07.01.2019,,81,,,60532640,tARFooWMOND,EUR,"11,10",,20140107,
```

Comment: Thank you Tomalak! Optimal solution and excellent advices. Chapeau

Comment: Make extra sure that you are not using `utf8` as the file encoding just because it happens to work. It's what I chose for my testing, it might not be correct encoding for your data. Double-check what encoding the SAP files are being exported as and what the CSV file you produce is expected to be. Adapt the encoding parameters accordingly.