# How to read special txt file as normal pandas dataframe. delimiter "|", encoding ANSI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a report coming out from SAP as txt file format, the encoding used (as per IT personnel) is "ANSI". And I can see the delimiter is "|".

This is my first time dealing with a file like this and all i want is to read it as normal pandas df but i can't manage to do so. I am sure i am doing something wrong but can't understand what!!!

I read some solution here like this link, but I kept getting empty results
[How to convert a SAP .txt extraction into a .csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58268816/how-to-convert-a-sap-txt-extraction-into-a-csv-file)

I would really appreciate any help because I am stuck with 12 of these files.

The file will look like here:

```
    5.04.2021 
Lieferungen mit Auftragsdaten                                                                                              1
    
    | Lieferung |   Pos|Angel.am  |VStl|LFArt| |
    |------------------------------------------|
    | 9888477351|000010|24.01.2020|LC01|ZLSO   |
    | 9888401282|000010|11.01.2020|LC03|ZLSO   |
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use read table and fix all problems manually, here goes:

```
import pandas as pd

t = \
"""
5.04.2021 
Lieferungen mit Auftragsdaten                                                                                              1
    
    | Lieferung |   Pos|Angel.am  |VStl|LFArt| |
    |------------------------------------------|
    | 9888477351|000010|24.01.2020|LC01|ZLSO   |
    | 9888401282|000010|11.01.2020|LC03|ZLSO   |
"""

with open('t.txt', 'w') as fn:
    fn.write(t)

df = pd.read_table('t.txt', sep="|", header=2)
df = df[1:]
df = df[df.columns[1:-2]]
df.columns = [c.strip() for c in df.columns]
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

|  | Lieferung | Pos | Angel.am | VStl | LFArt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9888477351 | 10 | 24.01.2020 | LC01 | ZLSO |
| 1 | 9888401282 | 10 | 11.01.2020 | LC03 | ZLSO |